# System.LoadLibrary() doesn't find Library

Tags: java

I have a library `/home/me/myfolder/mylib.so`

and when executing

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

I get the `/home/me/myfolder`. But if I try to load it:

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

This error happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mylib.so in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:11)
```

Already tried to use `mylib.so` instead. The library was created from Haskell Code.

Comment: It's looking for `Java2Haskell.so`, so you'll need to include that file in your library path as well as any additional linked libraries.

Comment: Oops, I changed Java2Haskell.so to mylib.so , but forgot to do this in the error message. So sadly, thats not the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux/Unix, I believe it will look for `lib<name>.so`, so try renaming your library to `/home/me/myfolder/libmylib.so`, and loading it with `System.loadLibrary("mylib");`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Program is still exploding, but due to errors in the lib this time. Thanks!